# DI setup with multiple instances of ILoggerProvider

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I want to add multiple instances of ILoggerProvider. The ILoggerProvider creates same loggers but with different values

```cs
// The constructor for the IloggerProvider looks something like below:

public MyLoggerProvider(IInterface1 val1, IInterface2 val2)
{
    // Do Something here
} 

// In my DI setup I want to add multiple instances of the provider like below:

public SetupLoggerProviders(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    var myloggerProvider1 = new MyLoggerProvider(val11, val12);
    serviceCollection.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider>(myloggerProvider1));
 
    var myloggerProvider2 = new MyLoggerProvider(val21, val22);
    serviceCollection.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<ILoggerProvider>(myloggerProvider2));
}
```

But this seems like a bad solution because I am newing up objects. How can I make this better?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

- `AddSingleton()` instead of `TryAddEnumerable()`, because `TryAddEnumerable()` would only keep one of the objects.
- Factory lambdas. That way the logger providers are only instantiated when needed, not inside `SetupLoggerProviders()`.

Minimal working solution:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

static class Program
{
    static int val11 = 11, val12 = 12, val21 = 21, val22 = 22;

    static void Main()
    {
        IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        SetupLoggerProviders(serviceCollection);

        foreach (var loggerProvider in serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<ILoggerProvider>>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(loggerProvider);
        }
    }

    static void SetupLoggerProviders(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(_ => new MyLoggerProvider(val11, val12));
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(_ => new MyLoggerProvider(val21, val22));
    }
}

interface ILoggerProvider { }

class MyLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    int val1, val2;

    public MyLoggerProvider(int val1, int val2)
    {
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"MyLoggerProvider({val1}, {val2})";
}
```

Output:

```
MyLoggerProvider(11, 12)
MyLoggerProvider(21, 22)
```